# cannot open file, access is denied. jGrasp error

Tags: java, jgrasp

I have a java project that was created in jGrasp that compiles and runs at first but once it is modified in any manner, it gives an error that it can't open file. I'm going to show you what the file looks like before I tried to modify it and what happens once it is modified. Is there a way to work around this error to open the file and work in it? I even tried commenting out what I had modified but it still denied me access.[image][image]

Comment: Could you save it in another text editor (Notepad++, Vim)?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. This is a class assignment for a college course. It has to be done in jGrasp because that's the program we use.

Comment: JGrasp is nothing more than an IDE.  Believe me, I know; I've tutored many students using it before.  What I'm trying to do is isolate the problem area.  If it's something with JGrasp, then you can save the file with another IDE/text editor - and seriously, I do recommend Notepad++ for Windows.  If it isn't, then you wouldn't be able to save the file with something else, and it's more systemic.

Comment: I just saved the file in Notepad++ but I since I only a student I don't know how to compile and run it in Notepad++ or even Eclipse because I tried Eclipse but I couldn't get it to run there either.

Comment: So now we know that it's a JGrasp issue.  I'd say reinstall JGrasp.  To compile your own classes, you can use `javac` from the command prompt.  I'd recommend talking with your teacher, classmates, or a TA about the preferred way to compile your assignments; I know that some teachers (for whatever inane reason) will insist that you use their tooling.

Comment: I like to add that once I close the file I can compile and run it but once I do any kind of changes to it, I'm denied access again until I close it and reopen it. The other files don't do that. It is just this one file. I downloaded it from a zip file that my instructor gave us.

Comment: Now all my other files are behaving the same way, denying me access. So it is a jGrasp issue. I guess I have to uninstall and install it again. Thanks.

Comment: I emailed my instructor and he reset the file, which I downloaded without the read only attribute. Now I can modify the class without problems.